# richfaces valuechange event won't trigger on selectOneMenu

Tags: jsf, richfaces, selectonemenu, valuechangelistener

I have two .xhtml pages, each containing a form to enter data for a selected object. They only differ in the object to select.

First Page:

```
<h:outputText value="Buchung:"/>
<h:selectOneMenu converter="#{orderConverter}" value="#{reportBean.selectedOrder}" valueChangeListener="#{reportBean.valueChange}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{orderBean.privateOrderList}" var="order" itemValue="#{order.ID}"/>
    <a4j:ajax event="valueChange" execute="@this"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Second Page

```
<h:outputText value="Auto:"/>
<h:selectOneMenu converter="#{vehicleConverter}" value="#{orderBean.selectedVehicle}" valueChangeListener="#{orderBean.valueChange}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{vehicleBean.vehicleList}" var="vehicle" itemValue="#{vehicle.licenseTag}"/>
    <a4j:ajax event="valueChange" execute="@this"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

The valueChange method of both backingBeans is basically the same, too:

ReportBean:

```
public void valueChange(ValueChangeEvent event){
if(null!=event.getNewValue()) {
    selectedOrder = (Order) event.getNewValue();
    }
}
```

OrderBean:

```
public void valueChange(ValueChangeEvent event){
if(null!=event.getNewValue()) {
    selectedVehicle = (Vehicle) event.getNewValue();
    }
}
```

As you can see, the object is converted before displaying but the conversion is just converting back and forth. Should not be the problem,

orderConverter for page 1 for Example:

```
@ManagedBean
@FacesConverter(value = "orderConverter")
public class OrderConverter extends GenericConverter implements Converter {

@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent uiComponent, String s) {
    int i = Integer.parseInt(s);
    return OrderDAO.getInstance().findById(i);
}

@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent uiComponent, Object o) {
    return  o.toString();
}
}
```

vehicleConverter finds the object based on the passed string, instead of parsing it to integer in before.
The "toString()" methods concarcenate some strings for identification in the SelectOneMenu, so this should not be the problem.

Yet, page 2 triggers the valueChangeEvent and page 1 does not!

The only difference I see is, that the "itemValue" attribute of the f:selectItems is a String (licenseTag of the vehicle) on page 2 and an integer (order ID) on page 1. Is this the cause for this event not to trigger? If so, how do i solve this when i dont have another identification for order?

Comment: You mean the AJAX request doesn't fire or the valueChangeListener doesn't execute?

Comment: In Debug-mode the valueChange() was not entered at any time. Nevertheless, i solved my problem with the valueChangeListener interface.